# What is the way to integrate Biometric Device with Web software through ASP.NET Technology?

Tags: asp.net, biometrics

I have different type of Biometric Devices but they all have there own software but i need some api type setup to just integrate the data on my own CRM for further calculation and Reporting as my own style

Comment: Do these devices provide api? If so, just use their api.

Comment: most of the time those device has some API, look for them as FCin suggested

Comment: The problem with "Just use their API" is that your it adds an entirely unknowable level of insecurity to your critical processes, and opens your network to Internet-of-Things vulnerability. A biometric device direct-POST-to-IP solution (if such a thing existed) would be ideal. Lots of great Raspberry Pi solutions for us DIYers :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to connect your biometric machines to your CRM, you should have web api supported biometric machines. You can find in google https://www.google.com/search?q=Web+API+Supported+Biometric+Machines, you will get list of machines.